# Drag and drop in preferences (reordering of items)

Tags: android, user-interface, drag-and-drop, preferences, android-gui

I have few items like this

```
<ListPreference android:key="key1"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:entries="@array/asd"
    android:entryValues="@array/asd1"
    android:defaultValue="109" android:dialogTitle="title"
    android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel" />
<ListPreference android:key="key2"
    android:title="@string/title2"
    android:entries="@array/asd2"
    android:entryValues="@array/asd22"
    android:defaultValue="109" android:dialogTitle="title"
    android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel" />
```

and they are all placed in one category . . ., the thing I want to do is to be able to reorder the items ( to put key2 before key1 with drag and drop)

is this possible at all in android and how can I do this ?, what methods should I override ?

After dragging the second item and doping above the first the items should be swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this example](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html)

It helps me a lot.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.